# Why don't Euler's formulas for torque apply to this problem?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, rigid-body-dynamics

In my mechanics class we were assigned problem 9.44 from "Introduction to Classical Mechanics" by David Morin as homework. The problem and figure are below:

> Two wheels of mass $m$ and moment of inertia $I$ are connected by a massless axle of length $l$, as shown in Fig. 9.61. The system rests on a frictionless surface, and the wheels rotate with frequency $\omega$ around the axle. Additionally, the whole system rotates with frequency $\Omega$ around the vertical axis through the center of the axle. What is the largest value of $\Omega$ for which both wheels stay on the ground?
>
> [image: A diagram of the problem]

Here is how I calculated torque with Euler's formulas:

Euler's torque formula says that $\tau_1 = I_1 \dot{\omega}_1 + (I_3 - I_2)\omega_2\omega_3$. If we let $I_1$ be the principal axis that initially points through the page, and $I_2$ be the principal axis that is parallel to the axle, we have $\tau_1 = (I_3 - I_2)\omega\Omega$. It's easy to see that $I_2 = 2I$, and we can calculate $I_3 = \frac{1}{2}ml^2 + I$ using axis theorems, so $\tau = (\frac{1}{2}ml^2-I)\omega\Omega$.

This torque is incorrect. The correct one (found [here](https://homework.study.com/explanation/two-wheels-of-mass-m-and-moment-of-inertia-i-are-connected-by-a-massless-axle-of-length-l-the-system-rests-on-a-frictionless-surface-and-the-wheels-rotate-without-frequency-omega-around-the-axle-additionally-the-whole-system-rotates-with-frequency-o.html)), uses $\tau = 2I\omega\Omega$, which is slightly different than the torque given by Euler's formulas. My question is, why don't Euler's formulas correctly calculate the torque in this system? And where does the value $\tau = 2I\omega\Omega$ come from?

Comment: How sure are you that a random answer found on study.com is correct?  I haven't checked the result myself, but I wouldn't necessarily trust it.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Our TA posted a similar solution (same torque). The torque comes from looking at a differential time step and projecting the angular momentum from before the rotation onto the principal axes after the rotation. This gives $\Delta L_1 = L_2 \sin(\Delta \theta) = L_2 \Delta \theta = (2I\omega)(\Omega \Delta t)$.

Comment: Hint: The two wheels are not a rigid body. They are TWO rigid bodies each with its own motion. So you cannot just combine the motion and apply the EOM at the center.

Comment: Surely a rigid body is one for which every particle maintains a constant distance from every other particle, ensuring that the body's shape and size do not change. And surely the wheels and axle form such a body.

Answer (score 0):

The Euler equation is:

$$\mathbf\Theta\, {\dot{\vec{O}}_m}+\vec O_m\times (\mathbf\Theta\,\vec O_m)=\vec \tau$$

with

\begin{align*}
  &\vec{O}_m=\begin{bmatrix}
               0 \\
               2\,\omega(t) \\
               \Omega \\
             \end{bmatrix}\quad,
 \mathbf\Theta=\begin{bmatrix}
           0 & 0 & 0 \\
           0 & I & 0 \\
           0 & 0 & 0 \\
         \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

you obtain

\begin{align*}
   &\vec\tau=\begin{bmatrix}
               -2\,I\,\Omega\,\omega \\
               I\,\dot{\omega} \\
               0 \\
             \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

notice that the inertia $~I_x~,I_y~,I_z$  of the axle are zero.(mass less)

---

**Edit**

[image]

with the parallel axis theorem the inertia  tensor, $~\mathbf\Theta_{xyz}~$  is:

\begin{align*}
  &\mathbf\Theta_{xyz}=  \mathbf \Theta_{w}-m\,\left[\vec r_{wo}\right]_\times
  \,\left[\vec r_{wo}\right]_\times
\end{align*}
where m is the mass of the wheel and $~\mathbf \Theta_{w}~$ is the wheel inertia .
$~\vec r_{wo}~$ is the vector from the center  of the wheel to the  coordinate system  $~xyz~$.

thus
\begin{align*}
  \mathbf\Theta_{xyz}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & I & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}&\underbrace{-m\,
   \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & -L/2 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
     L/2 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}\, \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & -L/2 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
     L/2 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\rm left\, wheel}\\
  &\underbrace{ -m\,
   \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & L/2 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
     -L/2 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}\, \begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 0 & L/2 \\
     0 & 0 & 0 \\
     -L/2 & 0 & 0 \\
   \end{bmatrix}}_{\rm right\, wheel}\\
&\mathbf\Theta_{xyz}=
   \begin{bmatrix}
     1/2\,m\,L^2 & 0 & 0 \\
     0 & I & 0 \\
     0 & 0 & 1/2\,m\,L^2 \\
   \end{bmatrix} 
\end{align*}

the result is now

\begin{align*}
  &\vec \tau=
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \tau_x \\
    \tau_y \\
    \tau_z \\
  \end{bmatrix}=
  \begin{bmatrix}
               \Omega\,\omega\,(m\,L^2 -2\,I)\\
               I\,\dot{\vec{\omega}} \\
               0 \\
             \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Comment: I don't understand why the axle being massless makes $I_z=0$. Don't the wheels  mass contribute to that moment of inertia?

Comment: @AlexWaese-Perlman , yes this is correct , I will edit my answer .